# How do I use javascript setTimout?

Tags: javascript

I have a small piece of javascript that I would like to use but need a delay before it's activated.

```
function sglClick(url) {
    window.setTimeout('location.href="http://'"+url",1500);
}
```

This is not working and I'm really stuck here.

---

Here is what I now have

```
function send(){

}

function sglClick(url) {
//    window.location.href="http://"+url;
    setTimeout(function send() { location.href = "http://" + url; },1500);
}
```

Comment: Never wrap code in quotes when passing it to "setTimeout", because this invokes "eval()", a function that should only ever be used when absolutely necessary. Instead, use an anonymous function like in alex's solution.

Comment: Hi, could you please show me what I should put into this new function? I'm sorry but I am really, really new to javascript.

Comment: Tim, your function is fine if you use (and if neccessary, adapt) my code. May I ask why you require this function? Perhaps there may be a better solution.

Comment: Sure Alex. I want to allow a user to single click or double click on a row of data. If the user single clicks then show page1 of it is a double click then show page 2. Problem is, when I double click, the onclick handler is kicking in first and taking me to page 1 when I want page 2. I figured that setTimout would be a good solution. Thanks so much for the help

Comment: @Tim: Use the exact code in alex's answer and you'll be fine. Your second code snippet doesn't work because you've given the function a name. While normal functions have names, anonymous functions don't have names. They are a "value" that can be passed around just like strings, arrays, and other data types. For learning more about functions in JavaScript, you may find https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Functions_and_function_scope and https://developer.mozilla.org/en/a_re-introduction_to_javascript of help.

Comment: Wow.. It works.. Would you please explain why? I don't have anything in the new function I created with the name send()

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try this

```
function sglClick(url) {
    setTimeout(function() { location.href = "http://" + url; },1500);
}
```

This is using an anonymous function to house your code. It should take approx 1.5 seconds to fire. I say approx because JavaScript is single threaded, and other function calls/etc can actually make the interval fire at a slightly different time (but 9/10 this is a non-issue)

It is also assuming you're sending things like this to the function

```
sglClick('www.google.com');
```

As your code is prefixing the argument with http://

I've always used this function as just simply setTimeout(), not as a method of the window object.

Comment: Hey Alex, thanks! This other function... What should go in it?

Comment: Which function are you referring to?

Comment: Well, I figured I would would make a new function and call it "send". Basically, I want to wait about half a second before sending the user to the url

Comment: When this function is invoked, it will automatically wait 1.5 seconds and send the user to the computed address. If you'd like, you can rename this function to send().

Comment: @alex: By the way, in JavaScript, "window.something" is the same as "something". So, "setTimeout" refers to the same function/method that "window.setTimeout" refers to.

Comment: Alex.. Thank you so much! I just wish I understood *why* it is working. The new function you had me create is empty. So how is it working?

Comment: @Tim: The new function isn't "empty". It contains the code 'location.href = "http://" + url;'. However, it has no name, which is why it is called an "anonymous function".

Comment: Whoops! In its commenting system, StackOverflow seems to turn anything that has http[colon]// into a link, so the code snippet in my previous comment didn't come out completely right...

Comment: Its weird because I deleted that function and it still works. In other words.. Alex wrote function() and I changed it to function send() then actually created a function called send. After I tested it with send() having an empty code block, I deleted it. It still works though. Why?

Comment: I'm sorry, if my last post was not clear, I can post my code up top.